# Second query to display data for only some rows of initial query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm really not sure if a nested query is what I need.

I'm working on a site where teachers can create quizzes to help their students learn. I have a simple query that echoes that quizzes that a logged in teacher has already created, based on the member's session id matching member_id in tbl_quiz_titles.

Beneath each quiz name is a button (in a form) that allows the teacher to go to another page to add a badge to the quiz, which the students can receive if they get a certain percentage, determined by the teacher.

Here is my current code:

```
session_start();
    include "mysqlpdo_connect.php";
        $my_quiz_query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_quiz_titles WHERE member_id = '{$_SESSION['member_id']}'") ;

$result_my_quiz_query = $my_quiz_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($result_my_quiz_query as $row_my_quiz_query) {


echo $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_id'] . ": " . $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_name'] . "<br/>

<form action=\"ebox_badge_new.php\" method=\"get\" style=\"float: left\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ref\" value=\"" . $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_id'] . "\" />              
    <button><img src=\"images/icons/Add_Badge_Btn.gif\" alt=\"Add badge to quiz\" width=\"100\" height=\"25\" border=\"0\" /></button>
</form>
<br/>
<br/>

 ";

        }
```

The problem is that this query shows the form button beneath every quiz name. Once a teacher has added a badge to their quiz, I no longer want them to see the form to add a badge for that particular quiz.

It should be noted that badges are stored in tbl_badges, with the quiz id being stored in the column  "badge_quiz_id".

My question is therefore: How do I change the code so that the form button only appears for those quizzes that do not already have a badge associated with them?

Ie:
    $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_name']

should be echoed for each quiz, but the form should only be shown  where $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_id']  is not seen in tbl_quiz_badges.badge_quiz_id ?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: you need JOIN in your query

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction "Your Common Sense".

This is what I came up with, which seems to do the trick:

```
   <?php
  session_start();
    include "mysqlpdo_connect.php";
        $my_quiz_query = $pdo->query("SELECT *
FROM    `tbl_quiz_titles`
LEFT JOIN 
   `tbl_badges` 
ON     `member_id` = '{$_SESSION['member_id']}'
    AND `quiz_id` = `badge_quiz_id`") ;





$result_my_quiz_query = $my_quiz_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($result_my_quiz_query as $row_my_quiz_query) {


echo $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_id'] . ": " . $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_name'] . "<br/>";

if ($row_my_quiz_query['badge_quiz_id'] == "")
{


echo"   <form action=\"ebox_badge_new.php\" method=\"get\" style=\"float: left\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ref\" value=\"" . $row_my_quiz_query['quiz_id'] . "\" />              
    <button><img src=\"images/icons/Add_Badge_Btn.gif\" alt=\"Add badge to quiz\" width=\"100\" height=\"25\" border=\"0\" /></button>
</form>
<br/>
<br/>

 ";
  }
        }
        ?>
```